# [Graph Problem algorithm]

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

I am new here . Please forgive me if there is anything wrong in that I am going to write .
So , my question is about one problem given in last round of codeforces , pretty easy to handle it , but I do not understand the other players` solutions .

THE PROBLEM :

We have a convex polygon and numbers it's vertices 1, 2, ..., n in clockwise order. Then starting from the vertex 1 , we draw a ray in the direction of each other vertex. The ray stops when it reaches a vertex or intersects with another ray drawn before. We repeat this process for vertex 2, 3, ..., n (in this particular order). And then we put a walnut in each region inside the polygon.
What is the minimum number of jumps we have to perform in order to collect all the walnuts?

I think the answer is equivalent to find the number of all those distinct regions / faces of that graph .

How could the answer be : $(n-2)^2$ .

Comment: It would be good if you edit the question to include what you tried and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: You say that you don't understand the other participants' solutions but you don't say what those solutions are or what you don't understand about them. What's your actual question?

Comment: David , the answer of the others was $(n-2)^2$ , but I understood why.

Comment: Is this a combinatorics question, or do you want an algorithm to solve some counting problem?

Comment: @Raphael is a counting problem , I am not interested in algorithm

Comment: Then why is this question here and not on [math.SE]? That is, what is the connection to computer science?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a counting problem. Here is my brief analysis and see if it makes any sense to you.

A key observation is to notice the answer is equal to the number of rays plus 1. Here is an explanation: Initially, there is 1 walnut on the polygon and no ray. Then, each extra ray will separate a region into two and thus increase the total number of walnut by 1.

What remains is to count the number of rays.

First of all, NONE of vertices can shoot itself. Then, I separate all vertices into three groups:

1. For Vertex 1. It CANNOT shoot rays to vertices 2 and N because of immediate neighborhood.

Then, the polygon has been triangulated and each region can be studied separately. Now, NONE of the remaining vertices can shoot ray to vertex 1 (because they have been shot by vertex 1 already).

2. For vertices 2 and N. Vertex 2 CANNOT shoot ray to vertex 3, and vertex N CANNOT shoot ray to vertex N-1 (because of immediate neighborhood too).
3. For vertices 3, 4, ... up to N-1. They CANNOT shoot ray to the TWO NEIGHBORING VERTICES.

At the end, the answer is

$1+Ray_{v_1} + Ray_{v_2, v_N} + Ray_{V-\{v_1,v_2,v_N\}}\\
= 1+1\times (N-3)+2\times(N-3)+(N-4)\times(N-3)\\
= (N-1)\times(N-3)+1$

which is equivalent to $(N-2)^2$

Notice that the formula may not make sense when $N<5$, but you can memorize it.

Comment: @penguina, if you found that this answer answered your question, you can thank user2107213 by accepting the answer if it is the most helpful answer you've received (and upvoting it once you get enough reputation to do that).  You can accept an answer by ticking the arrow to the left of the answer.